# ¿Cómo resolver Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, axios, jwt

Buen día a todos,

Tengo un API Rest en C#, y tengo varios métodos GET y POST en dicho API, todos los métodos los probé usando Postman y funcionaron a la perfección, todos me dan las respuestas que espero, el problema surge cuando estoy intentando consumirlos desde mi Front, he intentado usando Axios y Ajax y todos me arrojan la siguiente excepción:

• Axios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

• jQuery Ajax:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logré hacer que me saliera este error más exacto jaja:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creí que podría ser primero porque el API estaba en https y mi front en http, así que coloqué ambos en https y ambos en http y esto no lo resolvió.

La forma en como lo estoy consumiendo es la siguiente:

• Axios:

```
let url = this.apiSeguridad + "usuario/";              
let data = {
            Nit_ID: this.userInfo.nit_ID.ID,
            UserName: this.userInfo.userName.ID,
            Password: btoa(this.password),
            Public_IP: this.publicIP,
            Private_IP: this.localIP
           };
console.log(url, data);
let resultApi = await axios.post(url, data);
```

También intenté usando el siguiente código:

```
let url = this.apiSeguridad + "usuario/";
let config = {
            headers: {
                 "Content-Type": "application/json",
                 "cache-control": "no-cache"
                 }
             };
let data = JSON.stringify({
           Nit_ID: this.userInfo.nit_ID.ID,
           UserName: this.userInfo.userName.ID,
           Password: btoa(this.password),
           Public_IP: this.publicIP,
           Private_IP: this.localIP
           });
console.log(url, data);
let resultApi = await axios.post(url, data,config);
```

y no funcionó.

En Ajax intenté en formas similares pero era más para validar si la petición era válida pero arroja el mismo error, me interesa hacer que funcione en axios.

Las peticiones GET funcionan perfectamente, solo me ocurre el error en las peticiones POST.

La configuración que tengo del API en el web.config es esta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el método POST que quiero consumir está así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, ahora, donde creo que puede ser el problema es que estoy usando `JWT` en mi API y adicioné está línea de código en el `WebApiConfig.cs`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que se supone que debe validar el header para todas las solicitudes a métodos en los que yo tenga el atributo `[Authorize]`

Para implementar el JWT usé [esta web](https://enmilocalfunciona.io/construyendo-una-web-api-rest-segura-con-json-web-token-en-net-parte-ii/), allí fue donde tomé y añadí esa línea de código.

Quisiera su ayuda para poder resolverlo, no sé si es configuración del API o en como consumo el API desde axios o qué.

La solicitud desde postman funciona correctamente y me responde como yo quisiera, acá les dejo un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No le añado nada más a esa solicitud.

Gracias a la solicitud de Miguel Zarate para que usara Fiddler4 para verificar las solicitudes esto es lo que me muestra la herramienta:

• Solicitud desde el Postman:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

• Solicitud desde el Front:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta parece ser la diferencia más evidente entre los resultados:

• Postman:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

• Front:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo más curioso es que cuando elimino del web.config la cabecera `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` el Postman sigue haciendo la solicitud sin problemas, pero desde mi Front yo no puedo hacer ninguna solicitud GET hasta que la coloque nuevamente, pero continua el fallo con las solicitudes POST.

> CURL desde consola de Google Chrome:

• CMD:

```
curl "https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/" -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Referer: http://localhost:8080/" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36" -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "^{^\^"Nit_ID^\^":^\^"899999284^\^",^\^"UserName^\^":^\^"sasfdm^\^",^\^"Password^\^":^\^"NDU0NjU0NjU0^\^",^\^"Public_IP^\^":^\^"181.49.144.244^\^",^\^"Private_IP^\^":^\^"192.168.253.102^\^"^}" --compressed
```

• Bash:

```
curl 'https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"Nit_ID":"899999284","UserName":"sasfdm","Password":"NDU0NjU0NjU0","Public_IP":"181.49.144.244","Private_IP":"192.168.253.102"}' --compressed
```

• CMD: All:

```
curl "https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/1032494911" -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "Referer: http://localhost:8080/" -H "DNT: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36" -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" --compressed &
curl "https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/tipodocumento/899999284/1032494911" -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "Referer: http://localhost:8080/" -H "DNT: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36" -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" --compressed &
curl "https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/" -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Referer: http://localhost:8080/" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36" -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "^{^\^"Nit_ID^\^":^\^"899999284^\^",^\^"UserName^\^":^\^"sasfdm^\^",^\^"Password^\^":^\^"MTIzNDU2Nzg5^\^",^\^"Public_IP^\^":^\^"181.49.144.244^\^",^\^"Private_IP^\^":^\^"192.168.253.102^\^"^}" --compressed
```

• Bash All:

```
curl 'https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/1032494911' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' --compressed ;
curl 'https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/tipodocumento/899999284/1032494911' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' --compressed ;
curl 'https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"Nit_ID":"899999284","UserName":"sasfdm","Password":"MTIzNDU2Nzg5","Public_IP":"181.49.144.244","Private_IP":"192.168.253.102"}' --compressed
```

---

> El error radica en cómo enviar correctamente la DATA al método POST, dado que si se crea un método POST que no reciba data no hay problema, lo consume sin problemas, cuando recibo parámetros no lo hace, entonces **¿cómo envío correctamente esos datos con Axios?**

Cuando no coloco parametros en el API como `[FromBody]InfoEntryValidateUsuarioClass data` el comando `let resultApi = await axios.post(url);` funciona.

Si añado el `[FromBody]InfoEntryValidateUsuarioClass data` como parametro en el API y envio la data usando `JSON.stringify({...})` recibo `null` en los datos enviado, pero si no lo uso, me aparece nuevamente el error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error está en cómo enviar esos datos que está esperando el API, la clase a la que referencio es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class InfoEntryValidateUsuarioClass
    {
        public string Nit_ID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Public_IP { get; set; }
        public string Private_IP { get; set; }
    }
```

Y la data la estoy enviando así:

```
let data = JSON.stringify({
    Nit_ID: this.userInfo.nit_ID.ID,
    UserName: this.userInfo.userName.ID,
    Password: btoa(this.password),
    Public_IP: this.publicIP,
    Private_IP: this.localIP
});
```

---

Logré hacer que una solicitud Ajax funcionara, el código es el siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost:44377/api/usuario",
        data: {
                "Nit_ID": "899999284",
    "UserName": "sasfdm",
    "Password": "RmFiaWFuMTIzKg=2=",
    "Public_IP": "123.123.456.789",
    "Private_IP": "192.168.253.110"
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result)
        }
    });
```

Pero cuando uso el axios no funciona, en axios lo estoy haciendo así:

```
             let data =  {
                  "Nit_ID": "899999284",
                  "UserName": "sasfdm",
                  "Password": "RmFiaWFuMTIzKg=2=",
                  "Public_IP": "123.123.456.789",
                  "Private_IP": "192.168.253.110"                
              }; 
let resultApi = await axios.post("https://localhost:44377/api/usuario", data);
```

Alguna idea de qué me puede faltar?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97160/discussion-on-question-by-fabian-montoya-como-resolver-access-to-xmlhttprequest).

Comment: Añadí los ejemplos del código que hice que funcionara en Ajax pero no logro hacer para que funcione con Axios

Comment: Por favor, transforma todas las imágenes que sean de código a TEXTO, gracias por colaborar con el orden del sitio y la buena calidad de las preguntas :D

Comment: Aunque lo corregimos con un arreglo medio sencillo (ver conversación del chat) ahora al intentar consumir otra función Post pasa lo mismo y nuevamente, con Ajax funciona pero no con Axios

Comment: Por favor no edites tu pregunta colocando en el título: *SOLUCIONADO* ni respuestas en la misma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de verificar varias cosas, y con la ayuda de muchas personas en el chat que se abrió, encontramos que la solución está en una configuración del web.config y el CORS directamente en el API.

En el web.config se agregó lo siguiente:

```xml
<system.webServer>
     <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
          <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
          <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
     </handlers>
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>        
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Y en el archivo `WebApiConfig.cs` se agregó el paquete

```cs
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
```

Para adicionarle la seguridad de CORS, allí lo que se colocó fue:

```cs
var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

Dejando el archivo así:

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Configuración y servicios de API web

            //Configuración para verificar la seguridad del CORS
            var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(corsAttr);

            // Rutas de API web
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Y ya funcionó todo el tema de las solicitudes con Axios, tanto los GET como los POST.

Cuando solo necesitaba enviar data en el POST lo hice de la siguiente forma:

```js
let data = {
    Nit_ID: this.userInfo.nit_ID.ID,
    UserName: this.userInfo.userName.ID,
    Password: btoa(this.password),
    Public_IP: this.publicIP,
    Private_IP: this.localIP
};
//Verificamos los datos del usuario
let resultApi = await axios.post(
     "https://localhost:44377/api/usuario",
     data
);
let result = resultApi.data;
```

Para el envío de datos en la cabecera con axios, lo hice de la siguiente forma:

```js
let data = {
    Nit_ID: this.userInfo.nit_ID.ID,
    UserName: this.userInfo.userName.ID,
    Code: this.verificationCode
};
console.log(localStorage.getItem("DoubleFactorToken"));
let headers = {
    Authorization: localStorage.getItem("DoubleFactorToken")
};
let resultApi = await axios.post(
     "https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/verifydoublefactorcode",
     data,
     { headers: headers }
);

console.log(resultApi.data);
```

Muchas gracias a todos los que se tomaron su tiempo en colaborar.

Comment: Hola, puedes marcar alguna respuesta como solucionada? Gracias

Comment: EN 12 minutos marcaré esta como solucionada, no me deja el sistema aún jaja

Answer (score 3):

debes habilitar `CORS` en tu API. Para ello instala en paquete NuGet `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` y luego en el método `Register` que has mostrado añade

```
config.EnableCors();
```

También echa un vistazo [Habilitar solicitudes entre orígenes en ASP.NET Web API 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors)

También decora tu controller o método con el siguiente atributo para que acepte CORS.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Por supuesto adapta las propiedades del ejemplo

Comment: Ya lo hice y sigue sin funcionar, sin el CORS habilitado funciona con ajax, ve el final de la pregunta

Comment: Ok. Yo haría lo siguiente según documentación de axios. Elimina las comillas dobles de los nombres de los campos de tu json. `let data =  {
                  Nit_ID: "899999284",
                  UserName: "sasfdm",
                  Password: "RmFiaWFuMTIzKg=2=",
                  Public_IP: "123.123.456.789",
                  Private_IP: "192.168.253.110"                
              };`

Comment: Ejemplo obtenido de `https://flaviocopes.com/axios/`

Comment: Así lo tenía originalmente y fue cuando salió por primera vez el error. Es más, así lo tengo actualmente

Comment: Hola @FabianMontoya, he editado mi respuesta para que añadas algo a tu controlador

Answer (score 2):

Veo un par de cosas de los dos últimos pantallazos de fiddler:

1.- Desde el front le pasas un header OPTIONS que no le gusta (en la respuesta te lo dice).

2.- Y mas importante, al hacer la peticion post los datos que envies han de ir codificados en la peticion post (no van como query string o sea, como parte de la URL). Si te fijas, en tu peticion desde postman se abren llaves y ahi se pasan 5 datos, eso no lo tienes en la petición desde tu codigo, y eso es lo que hace que no te funcione. Que tengas alguna diferencia en los headers no suele ser determinante.

Siento no ayudarte más, por si te sirve de ejemplo, desde C# lo tengo hecho y es mas o menos asi: (pero ni idea en js o con las librerias que indicas, que sin duda será muy diferente)

```
    string URL = "URLaVisitar";
    FormUrlEncodedContent contenidoPost = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Nit_ID", "valor"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserName", "valor"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", "valor"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Public_IP", "valor"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Private_IP", "valor")
        });

    var BResult =  cliente.PostAsync(URL, contenidoPost).Result;
```

Deberas encontrar la funcion en js que te crea el contenido codificado para adjuntar a la solicitud post. Luego, como te comentaba sobre los headers, eso es mas facil, y aunque no sean exactamente iguales a los que consigues con Postman, no deberia haber mucho problema.

Comment: Entiendo, y se supone que eso se resolvería al enviar la data con `JSON.stringify` pero aún así no hay éxito en la solicitud, ni siquiera copiando el CODE que genera Postman, puedes ayudarme con ejemplo de solicitud?, yo no encuentro dicho problema con el envío de los datos :c

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, el error está en cómo estoy enviando la data, hice otro método POST sin parámetros y lo consume sin problemas, ahora tengo que buscar es como se envían esos datos jaja