# from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: spring-boot

buenas tardes.

Estoy teniendo un inconveniente a la hora de realizar una petición desde una aplicación angular a las rutas que se definen como no libres, es decir que se debe de acceder a través de un token, me marca el siguiente error: from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Esto no me pasa con las rutas que si son accesibles para todos desde la aplicación angular y tampoco me pasa desde postman, desde postman puedo consumir un enpoint con el bearer token sin problemas, pero desde la aplicación angular me marca el error que te comento arriba. he investigado por varias horas pero no he logrado resolverlo.

Nota: del lado del back end manejo microservicios y el gateway es spring cloud gateway

¿alguien sabe a que se debe?

Dejo el código:

código del SprinSecurityConfig del microservicio Gateway:

```
package com.dda.gateway.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.SecurityWebFiltersOrder;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilterr;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity) {
        return serverHttpSecurity.authorizeExchange().
                pathMatchers("/dda/v1/autenticacion/oauth/**").permitAll().
        pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/dda/v1/cursos/**").permitAll().
                anyExchange().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterAt(jwtAuthenticationFilterr, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .csrf().disable().build();
    }
}
```

=================================================================================
código del AuthenticationManagerJwt del microservicio Gateway:

```
package com.dda.gateway.security;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
public class AuthenticationManagerJwt implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {


    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        return Mono.just(authentication.getCredentials().toString())
                .map(token -> {
                    SecretKey llave = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Base64.getEncoder().encode("llaveSecreta%%$##$#$%&/(/)()==".getBytes()));
                    return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(llave).build().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
                })
                .map(claims -> {
                    String username = claims.get("user_name", String.class);

                    List<String> roles = claims.get("authorities", List.class);
                    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);

                });
    }

}
```

=================================================================================

código del JwtAuthenticationFilter del microservicio Gateway:

```
package com.dda.gateway.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.ReactiveSecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter implements WebFilter{

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION))
                .filter(authHeader -> {
                    System.out.println(authHeader);
                    return authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ");})
                .switchIfEmpty(chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.empty()))
                .map(token -> {
                    System.out.println(token);
                    return token.replace("Bearer ", "");})
                .flatMap(token -> authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, token)))
                .flatMap(authentication -> chain.filter(exchange).contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication)));
    }

}
```

=================================================================================

application.yaml del microservicio gateway:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: '*'
            allowedHeaders: '*'
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - PUT
              - DELETE

  application:
    name: gateway
server:
  port: 10480
eureka:
  client:
    prefer-same-zone-eureka: true
```

=================================================================================
application.properties del microservicio gateway:

```
#Microservicio cursos
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=msdcursos
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://msdcursos
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates=Path=/dda/v1/cursos/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters=StripPrefix=2

#Microservicio Administración
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=msdadministracion
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://msdadministracion
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates=Path=/dda/v1/administracion/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters=StripPrefix=2

#Microservicio Autenticación 
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=msdautenticacion
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=lb://msdautenticacion
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates=Path=/dda/v1/autenticacion/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters=StripPrefix=3
```

=================================================================================
Código del AuthorizationServerConfig del microservicio autenticación:

```
package com.dda.msdautenticacion.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhancerChain;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private InfoAdicionalToken infoAdicionalToken;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("angularApp")
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("12345"))
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {

        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(infoAdicionalToken, accessTokenConverter()));

        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        tokenConverter.setSigningKey(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("llaveSecreta%%$##$#$%&/(/)()==".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        return tokenConverter;
    }


}
```

=================================================================================

Código del InfoAdicionalToken del microservicio autenticación:

```
package com.dda.msdautenticacion.configuration;

import com.dda.generico.document.Administrador;
import com.dda.msdautenticacion.service.AdministradorService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhancer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class InfoAdicionalToken implements TokenEnhancer {

    @Autowired
    private AdministradorService administradorService;

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        Map<String, Object> info = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Administrador administrador = administradorService.obtenerPorUsuario(authentication.getName());
        info.put("nombre", administrador.getNombre());
        info.put("apellido", administrador.getApellido());
        info.put("correo", administrador.getCorreo());
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(info);

        return accessToken;
    }

}
```

=================================================================================

Código del SpringSecurityConfig del microservicio autenticación:

```
package com.dda.msdautenticacion.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEventPublisher eventPublisher;
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
        .and().authenticationEventPublisher(eventPublisher);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

}
```

=================================================================================

El controlador del microservicio de administración que se quiere consumir:

```
package com.dda.msdadministracion.controller;

import com.dda.msdadministracion.service.AdministracionCursoService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/administracion")
public class AdministracionController {

    @Autowired
    private AdministracionCursoService administracionCursoService;

    @GetMapping("/{activo}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> obtenerTodas(@PathVariable Short activo) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(administracionCursoService.obtenerCursos(activo));
    }

}
```

=================================================================================

Service de la aplicación Angular para iniciar sesión y obtener el token:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {Administrador} from "../models/administrador";
import {BASE_PUNTO_FINAL} from "../config/configuracion";
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AutenticacionAdministradorService {

  urlAutenticacion = BASE_PUNTO_FINAL + 'autenticacion/oauth/token';

  constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient) { }


  iniciarSesion(administrador: Administrador): Observable<any> {

    const credenciales = btoa('angularApp' + ':' + '12345');

    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credenciales
    });

    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('grant_type', 'password');
    params.set('username', administrador.usuario);
    params.set('password', administrador.clave);
    console.log(params.toString());
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.urlAutenticacion, params.toString(), { headers: httpHeaders });
  }
}
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error CORS policy](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/298115/error-cors-policy)

Comment: no :(  si están en el mismo origen, el problema es cuándo un enpoint está restringido y quiero acceder desde una petición en angular me manda ese error y no el 401 que debería mandarme, si hago la petción desde postman todo sale bien, no marca el error, solo desde la aplicación en angular