# Consulta sobre API Rest Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, api, spring-boot

Tengo una API Rest Java Spring Boot con oAuth, el problema es que habilito GET y POST con .antMatchers y desde Postman las dos solicitudes funcionan bien, pero desde Angular o desde fetch javaScript nativo me da `error: 401` y `http://localhost:8080/v1/clientes`. (Razón: `encabezado CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' faltante`).

Estará Postman enviando alguna cabecera que se me esta pasando por alto al hacerlo desde Angular?

Por que desde Postman logro hacer el POST sin token? y desde el navegador no?

Dato extra: el GET si funciona desde Angular o JS nativo.
Testeado desde Firefox y Chrome. La API necesita que solo el POST solicite token.

Gracias de ante mano, saludos

Comment: No es que haya que hacerlo como postman, es que postman sólo quiere mostrarte qué pasa al llamar un endpoint. Toda la validación de CORS, viendo los encabezados de referer y tal se va a ver al navegar. Tu configuración del lado del servicio está incompleta. Revisa [esta pregunta y su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/298115/error-cors-policy)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alfabravo, me faltaba configurar cORS en la configuración de recursos. Saludos