# Error Cors NodeJS

Tags: c#, nodejs, api, cors

Estoy teniendo un problema con la solicitud hacia mi *API* desde mi programa en *C#*,
me está dando error de cors (Desde la web si que me funciona porque esta en la whitelist la ip, pero desde el programa me da un error la solicitud cors)

La api esta creada en *Express*.

Mi Cors:

```
const dominiosPermitidos = [url];
const corsOptions = {
    origin: function(origin, callback) {
        console.log(origin);
        
        if (dominiosPermitidos.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            //El origen del request esta permitido
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback(new Error('No permitido por Cors'))
        }
    }
}    

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

La llamada en c#:

```
url = "127.0.0.1/api/datos";
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream myStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myStream);
//Leemos los datos
string Datos = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myStreamReader.ReadToEnd());

dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Datos);

return data;
```

error c# [image: error]

error api [image: error]

¿Debería desactivar Cors?

Comment: Estas consumiendo la api desde tu programa en C#, no?

Comment: Si, desde el navegador si que me funciona, pero quiero hacer un panel en una aplicación de escritorio y no me deja @JoseMgz_Ux

Comment: Pregunta, ¿qué dominio tiene una aplicación de escritorio? Podrías agregarle algún custom header, como un `x-app-top-secret` con un simple GUID de validación.

Comment: Intenta con `url = "http://127.0.0.1/api/datos";` el tema es extenso, lecturas sugeridas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/221031/822 + https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/298146/822

Comment: He estado probando, cuando accedo desde mi front-end con el puerto definido en la whitelist del cors me funciona, pero a la hora de acceder desde mi apliicación en c# no me deja, aparte en la función de cors al loguear origin me devuelve undefinied

Comment: Implementaste los cors en el Program.cs? `app.UseCors()`